# Actionscript 3.0 movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, flash-cs6

I'm building where you connect dots by drawing a line between them. Now I want to make the stars move if you touch it. So, this is how I set up a level.

```
new DTLevelConfig(15000, [
            new DTLevelConfigStar(275, 109, 4), 
            new DTLevelConfigStar(139, 232, 3), 
            new DTLevelConfigStar(227, 248, 4), 
            new DTLevelConfigStar(318, 248, 4), 
            new DTLevelConfigStar(411, 232, 3), 
            new DTLevelConfigStar(235, 318, 3), 
            new DTLevelConfigStar(315, 318, 3)
        ], [
            new DTLevelInitialConnection(2, 3, true)
        ], false),
```

The DtLevelConfig is a star and the following are the coordinates. I want to add the following:

```
if(starIsClicked){
    star x coordinate increases by 100

}
```

I'm not very experienced in AS.. Thanks

Comment: if the star is a DisplayObject (sprite, movieclip..etc) you can just do `myStar.x += 100` and flash will automatically render it 100 pixels away in the next frame. anyway, i'm not sure what your question is here exactly. firstly you should store a reference to your stars, add a mousevent listener to them, and increase the x in the handler

Comment: i guess DTLevelConfig handles the stars, so if you just move the stars the lines connecting them won't necessarily follow unless specified